# Saving data from pyqt tableview in mssql

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtableview

My problem is figuring out how I can save 1000s of tableviews in a ms sql table.

The user of a program fills data into a qtable view and this is stored as a nested list in a json file. I want to move to a ms sql database but can't find a good way to store a tableview in a sql table. The tableviews vary in size from 2x2 to 20x20 cells.

Having one sql table per tableview seems a bit excessive and I'm sure there are better ways to oranize the data?

Comment: I do not understand you, maybe if you provide a [mcve] we could help you

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for your reply, Ive tried to rephrase the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977549/how-to-store-10-000s-of-tables-of-different-size-in-a-sql-database) Its not really code related, but perhaps more how i should organize data i sql database