# How to organize 10.000s of tables of different size in a SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a program where the user fills data into a table. The tables all have different sizes, some are 3x2, others are 30x20. 
Its just like an excel sheet and looks like this, where the user can add rows and columns as much as she needs them. These are charts related to products so each table has a unique product number

[image: just an example of one possible table]

Whats the best way to organize this data in a SQL database? 
Is it one SQL table per user generated table?

This seems excessive as i would end up with a database with 10000s of tables. Are there other, better ways to store the data? Can i combine it into one SQL table?

Comment: How Are the values in these tables related

Comment: by a product number, they are different kinds of charts related to a product with an unique product number

Comment: Not one table, but you can and definitely should combine them into a smaller number of tables.

Comment: This is probably more opinion based since the requirements you shared are so high-level. You might consider either an `XML` column (RecordId, UserId, DataXML) or you could store the cells in a table (RecordId, RowNum, ColNum, DataValue, UserId)

Comment: If you can describe what you are trying to store with as much detail as possible, I'm sure you will get a good solution.

Comment: tried again, but i find it hard to describe. Im not sure if i should use another word than "table" for the data the user types in

Comment: @JasonW thanks, i think ill try to store the data by RowNum and ColNum!

Comment: You are simply not providing enough information for anyone to even guess what schema you should use.

Comment: @DourHighArch Im very new to SQL but Im trying my best. Ill try it one more time here. I have many tables (excel sheets if you wish) of varying size. Some have 3x2 (rowsXColumns) Other can be much larger. I want to store these tables (excel sheets) in a MS SQL Server database. Each table (excel sheet) have a unique product number. What is the best option for organizing and saving my tables (excel sheets) in my sql server database?

Answer (score 2):

You can make SQL tables like

```
table_header
- id
- rows
- cols

table_detail
- header_id
- row
- col
- value
```

Then to store a table you create a header record and add the contents one entry at a time. To read the table back you would basically just pull all data for the table, maybe with an `ORDER BY` if you want to make parsing back into the table easier. Something like that.

Comment: and the `user_id` too